# jQuery animation affects sibling input elements when using a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery sliding input snippet which animates the width of an input element when it is focused to make it wider:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focus(function() {
    var elemWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).animate({
        width: elemWidth + 50,
    }, 300);
  });
  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focusout(function() {
    var elemWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).animate({
        width: elemWidth - 50,
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

Up until recently, I was not using a variable `elemWidth` - rather I hardcoded the standard width of an input in at 200px. However I now have some inputs which need to be 400px wide, so instead of tacking on additional code for each different size element, I simply grab the width element being focused and add my 50px to it.

It does actually work, however, I have discovered that on large forms, when I tab across fields fast enough so 2-3 can be animating simultaneously, the elements before the active one can shrink further than their original width, down to 150px.

I believe I know why this is happening (the variable `elemWidth` is changing as I tab across inputs), but I have no idea how to prevent it. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure, but you can try to delete your var :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).width()+ 50,
    }, 300);
  });
  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focusout(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).width()- 50,
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that when the `focus` triggers, it begins to animate the div, let's say from 200px to 250px. So it goes 200px, 201px, 202px. Then, quickly, `focusout` triggers. `focusout` checks the element's width, which is currently 202px, and then begins to animate it from 202px to 152px, which is the current width minus 50. So, that's how it's going down to 150px.

What you need to do is `stop` the animation if a new animation takes over, and jump to the end of the animation, which is exactly what jQuery's `stop` function does. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

So both of your `focus` and `focusout` animation functions should look something like this:

```
$(this).stop(true, true);
var elemWidth = $(this).width();
$(this).animate({
    width: elemWidth + 50 + "px",
}, 300);
```

`.stop(true, true)` will stop the current animation, clear the animation queue, and advance the animation to the end. Then the new animation function will take over.

Also, you should make sure you're setting your `width` to "px" :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, but nope - it's still happening, even with `stop(true, true)` prepended to the animate function. Very weird.

EDIT: Just cleared my cache to make sure it wasn't stuck. Nope, still not working.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it so that it checks the `width` after the `stop`, not before. Should work now, but it looks like you've already got it working with the accepted answer. Still, `stop`ing your animations is good practice if you plan to be making animations that stack up on top of each other.

Comment: +1, thanks for the help and the fix. I'll have a read up of the `stop` functionality, because I do understand how it could be useful.